# wasapi loopback to unity 2020 audio source or webrtc

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, buffer, pcm

Can anyone help me? I am sending live audio from WASAPI into Unity, and I want it to play back as a audio clip in the scene, or send it directly to WebRTC.

There are several issues. Mainly, I tried using wavutility.cs to convert the file to a audio clip, but it is unrecognized PCM data.

The bytes are incoming in to my main mono and are coming into my coroutine.

I'll post more code if i can get some help from anyone who knows what's going on with audio coding.

I can't find anyone who knows about this stuff, so I'm reaching out to stack for help now.

here:

```
    IEnumerator Run4() {
    WavUtility w = new WavUtility();

    WasapiLoopbackCapture _loopbackCapture = _realtimeAudio._loopbackCapture;

    SoundInSource _soundInSource = new SoundInSource(_loopbackCapture);
    _singleBlockNotificationStream = new SingleBlockNotificationStream(_soundInSource.ToSampleSource());
    _realtimeSource = _singleBlockNotificationStream.ToWaveSource();

    Byte[] buffer = new byte[_realtimeSource.WaveFormat.BytesPerSecond / 2];
 
    _soundInSource.DataAvailable += (s, ea) =>
    {
        while (_realtimeSource.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            print(buffer.Length);

            print(_realtimeSource.WaveFormat);

            Playclip2( WavUtility.ToAudioClip(buffer));

        }
    };
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

Comment: This question is a little unclear. "There are several issues." It's best to stick to one question in SO, which seems to be about the format of incoming PCM data. But what do you mean by "convert the file" — it sounds like you're dealing with a live incoming stream? What do you mean by "my main mono"? Do you mean a class derived from `MonoBehaviour`? Finally I suggest you drop the last 2 paragraphs as they don't add anything — if someone wants more detail/code, they'll ask here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.